# VIM Browse to a different disk in NetRw window

Tags: vim

I'm running gVim 7.3 on Windows 7. Is there a way when one is in a :Explore / NetRw 
window to switch to another disk?

For example, if I enter:

```
:Hex D:
```

is there a NetRw command that I can enter in this window to switch to exploring files on 
my C: drive?

Answer (score 2):

`:Ex C:` should do the trick: it replaces the current listing with the listing of `C:`.